# Why is the callback for `stream.write` not called in Object mode

Tags: node.js, node-streams

In this snippet, we create a passthrough stream and write 20 integers to it

```js
const stream = require('stream');
const ps = new stream.PassThrough({objectMode: true});

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const writeable = ps.write(JSON.stringify({n: i}), () => {
        console.log('write', i);
    });
}

ps.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('error', err);
});
```

I would expect the callback (`console.log('write', i);`) to be called once for each iteration of the loop for a total of 20 logs. In reality, it is only called 15 times:

```
write 0
write 1
write 2
write 3
write 4
write 5
write 6
write 7
write 8
write 9
write 10
write 11
write 12
write 13
write 14
write 15

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is that?

Additionally, If I change the transform stream to no *not* support object mode (i.e. {objectMode: false}), then all writes are competed. What is the inherent difference between the two that causes this discrepancy?

Comment: Not fully sure why it's behaving in the way it's behaving, but the `write` callback is only fired when the data is flushed. If you add a consumer for the stream (e.g. `ps.on('data', console.log)`) it will log all the data. Again, not sure why yet!

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#buffering This might be useful to explain the behvaiour you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks. @Sophie correct, adding a data handler works as expected. As does adding a custom write method.

Comment: The provided looks very relevant. The number of logs is directly correlated to the highWatermark value, hWm=20 logs 18 objects, hwm=6 logs 4 objects. Looks like the number of objects logged is generally hWm-2. The default is 16 for object mode and indeed running it again now logs 14 objects. For non object streams the default is 16kb, which also explains why in non object mode we can write a larger number of values.

Comment: @Sophie do u have a reference for the callback only being called on flush?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#writableendchunk-encoding-callback See the `callback` argument description - "Callback for when this chunk of data is flushed"